# В какой части приложения хранить запросы, которые не имеют отношения к сущности

Tags: android, http, best-practice

Подскажите пожалуйста, где необходимо в приложении размещать запросы к API, которые не имеют отношения к сущности чтобы размещать их в `RemoteRepository`?

Конкретный пример, запрос на восстановление пароля или авторизации пользователя в приложении. Т.е. они не имеют прямого отношения к `Repository`, чтобы хранить их там.

Под `Repository` я подразумеваю концепцию, которая используется в примерах описанных [здесь](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture).

Comment: В вопросе не хватает двух очень важных момента: 1) Что вы подразумеваете под сущностью 2) Что вы подразумеваете под Repository.
Не гугл на ста страницах, а именно вы.

Comment: @rjhdby сущность - объект данных, а репозиторий - хранилище этих данных.

Comment: По хорошему, `RemoteRepository` НЕ должен реализовывать логику сетевого обмена. За сетевой обмен у вас должен отвечать какой-нибудь `NetworkModule` или `ApiRequests` или как вам угодно. И ваш `RemoteRepository` и `UserManagment` и все остальные, кому нужен сетевой обмен, должны работать через него.

Comment: @rjhdby, т.е. если мне, к примеру, нужно будет выполнить авторизацию или восстановление пароля, то я могу просто из `Presenter` вызвать этот модуль сетевых запросов?

Comment: По хорошему, у вас должен быть класс, отвечающий за логику работы с пользователем `User`, уже в котором должны быть метод `resetPassword`, который дергает метод `NetworkService.sendRequest(new ResetPasswordRequest(user)...)`
Как-то так. Почитайте про MVC/MVP и им подобные